# Navigation folders are still displaying

Tags: css, menu, nav, squarespace

Trying to build my first website on Squarespace without any experience in coding.

I have a nav menu with multiple dropdown folders with individual pages nested inside; **Projects**\Identity, **Commercial**\Graphics etc.

When I click on a nested page I'd like the current selected folder on the menu to stay active, showing the user which page they're on.

I've tried putting this in my css:

`#topNav nav .folder-collection ul { border-style: none; }
 .subnav {background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0) !important;}
.subnav{height:auto!important}`

But this just leaves all the dropdown folders and their nested pages displayed.

Here's my [website](https://www.ossiewilliams.com/allprojects/).

Is there a way I can fix this? Thanks.

Comment: When you navigate to a new webpage, the HTML and CSS reset, so that's a job for server side coding like PHP, or in rare cases, JavaScript. Maybe there is a setting in SquareSpace that draws the menus and "highlights" the current folder?

Comment: Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the last line in the CSS you tried with:

```
.active-folder .subnav {
  height: auto !important;
}
```